# (Advanced Rest Client ,Postman) Vs chrome browser http request

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, http

I am trying to make a Http post request from my angularjs application using $http provider. $http provider is nothing just an angular wrapper for xmlHttprequest object. For a POST request , I am getting response by using Advanced Rest Client /Postman, But the same call is not finishing with angularjs http call.

Advanced Rest Client/Postman sending content-type:application/json.

So my question is , What difference it makes for calls going from  Advanced Rest Client/Postman Or a browser?